# Accessing the same Javascript function from different HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html

For example in **page1.html** I have:

```
    <input type="radio" id="id1" onclick="change()">Radio Button</input>
```

In **page2.html** I have :

```
    <a href="page3.html" id="id2">Link</a>
```

Clicking the radio button on **page1.html** should change the value of the href attribute in **page2.html**.

Javascript (*js_file.js*):

```
function change()
{
    if(document.getElementById(id1).checked)
        {
            document.getElementById(id2).href="page4.html";
        }  
}
```

This code will not work since id1 and id2 do not exist on the same page.

Is there any method where 2 or more html pages can simultaneously access a javascript function?

Assuming I have included this :

```
<script src="js_file.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

in both the HTML pages within the *head* tag.

I am trying to avoid server side programming as it is an embedded web server and can only be programmed in C language.

Comment: Make use of querystrings.

Comment: When action happens on page1, store the result using LocalStorage. When you load page2, check LocalStorage for it and if it exists, load the data from LocalStorage.

Comment: This question shows a lack of understanding of how web works. If you want to do something like this, you need a server side language not JS, or js + websockets if you're doing it realtime.

Comment: Exactly, what are you trying to do? What is the context?

Comment: Sorry, But I am trying to avoid server side programming as it is an embedded web server and can only be programmed in C language...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on for size.

**Page1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    var urlRadios = document.getElementsByName('urlSelector');
    var i, n = urlRadios.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        urlRadios[i].addEventListener('click', onUrlRadioChange, false);
}

function onUrlRadioChange(evt)
{

    localStorage.destUrl = this.getAttribute('dest');
    localStorage.destTxt = this.getAttribute('msg');
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Pick destination of link on page 2</h3>
    <input type='radio' msg='No page selected' dest='none' checked name='urlSelector'>none</input>
    <input type='radio' msg='Page 3' dest='page3.html' name='urlSelector'>page3.html</input>
    <input type='radio' msg='Page 4' dest='page4.html' name='urlSelector'>page4.html</input>
    <hr>
    <a href='page2.html'>Page 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    if (localStorage.destUrl != 'none')
        byId('tgtLink').href = localStorage.destUrl;
    byId('tgtLink').innerHTML = localStorage.destTxt;
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Destination was set by page 1</h3>
    <a id='tgtLink'>Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can do this is by passing data between pages using `hidden` HTML elements.

**Page1**

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" onclick="change.js">Radio Button</input>
```

**Page2**

```
<input type="hidden" name="radio1" value="XXX">
```

Of course, you'll have to have `Page1` upload the form to the server, and have the server generate `Page2` with the `hidden` elements populated.

Comment: Don't need no stinkin' server, nor a hidden form element for that matter. :p You can easily do this using javascript and files that are run on a local machine - don't even need to access them via localhost.

Comment: @enhzflep enlighten us ?

Comment: @enhzflep Yes, yes, things could be crammed into weird nooks and crannies -- you could hide things in `window.name` -- but if there is no server to process the form, then whats the use of collecting the data.

Comment: @enhzflep Please do illustrate how it is done, as it may be very helpful for my project

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which might work if the structure of the sites allow this: window.opener 
Let's say page 1 opens page 2 as a popup (so both windows are kept opened), then you could access everything from page 1 through window.opener. 
You can even test this here. Open any link on this site (whithin the domain of stackoverflow, else that would be XSS) in a new window, then open the JavaScript console of that new window and enter: window.opener.document.title = "YAY!"
At least that's an easy way to avoid using local storage etc.